# How to programatically initiate LineString Draw in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to activate draw and place the first point when a action is clicked on a  feature. This will then create a single line string to the next point where the marker will move to.

However I am having issues initiating the draw feature start point programatically so that my next click would be the second and final point of the line string.

I have tried implementing using:

```
 function startmove(coords) {

 interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                        type: 'LineString',
                        createFeature: coords,
                        source: source
                    });
  map.addInteraction(interaction);

 }
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look for  [ol3 example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html) for creating and editing feature

Comment: Thanks for your response, however its not clear in that example how to programatically set the first point of a line string.

Comment: @justnorm, look at this: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944733/open-layers-3-initialize-draw-interaction-with-first-node-on-linestring), but private func *startDrawing_* might be not available, and I don't know if I could create MouseEvent('click') with *coords * and fire it

Comment: My friend you are a hero! Ive been working on that for so long and searched so hard. This article helped massively!! Its a shame it has to be hacked in this way and isn't part of OL3 as default. But great find thank you!